# How to get private IPs of instances in amazon web services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get all the private IP addresses of instances running in my aws account.

Therefore I tried following command.

```
/usr/share/ec2-api-tools-1.5.2.5/bin/ec2-describe-instances |grep "INSTANCE" |awk '{print $13}'
```

but problem is that some instances having public IP and some are not.

Therefore column of private IP changes and in above command $13 does not give expected result.

Therefore kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, upgrade to the [newer version of the AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), then use this command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].NetworkInterfaces[*].PrivateIpAddresses[*].PrivateIpAddress' --output text
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. However updating to newer version of the AWS CLI may create problem as some other scripts are set on servers to create snapshot,  to get new spot machines. So is there any other way to get the expected result.

Comment: The new unified AWS CLI version should be able to live alongside the older service-specific version you are using now.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install newer version of AWS CLI as following syntax resolved my case.

```
ec2-describe-instances --filter "instance-state-name=running" --show-empty-fields | grep INSTANCE | awk '{print $18}'
```

In above syntax I first filtered output to running instances and then filled empty fields with (NIL) so each line gets divided into equal columns and then by using awk command I got required column (i.e. in my case Private IP address of each machine)